# How to post process Spring boot properties?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have defined some external properties in my main class as follows:

```
@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true),
        @PropertySource(value = "file:/opt/app/conf/database.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true),
        @PropertySource(value = "file:/opt/app/conf/overrides.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
})
```

For some of the properties I would like to do some post processing, for example encrypting or enrichment before they are actually used by any beans. One such property is `spring.datasource.password`

I have done the following:

1. Write an `ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext>` and tried to process those properties in the `initialize()` method

```java
public class MyApplicationContextInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        ConfigurableEnvironment environment = applicationContext.getEnvironment();
        String value = environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.password");
        System.out.println("The value in initializer is " + value);
        System.out.println("The database url in initializer is " + environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
        System.out.println("The database username in initializer is " + environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
    // .. other code
    }
}
```

and included the above class in the `META-INF/spring.factories` as follows:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer=com.myapp.MyApplicationContextInitializer
```

I am seeing `null` values in all of the above properties that are printed though both `database.properties` and `overrides.properties` are present. They are the *very first* statements to be printed (even before the *banner*)

2. Another approach I tried is `org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor` and adding in `META-INF/spring.factories` as

```
org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor=com.myapp.PropertiesProcessor
```

But still, I get the same *null* value.

> Interestingly, when I pass in the
> `-Dspring.config.location="file:/opt/app/conf/database.properties, file:/opt/app/conf/overrides.properties"`
> system property before executing the *war*, it works i.e. the values are printed.

But I do not want to manually pass in the system property at runtime. Is there a way to do it?
What is wrong with my code or approach. Are there any other ways of doing the *post-processing* before actually creating the beans?

Comment: Remove the `@PropertySource` and use the `spring.config.additional-location` and friends to load the config. Then you can use an `EnvironmentPostProcessor` to do the decryption.

Comment: @M.Deinum Is there an annotation or is it just a system property?

Comment: It is a system/environment/ whatever you like property. Also encrypting like that won't work, you would need to wrap the `ProperyySource` in a `PropertySource` that does the decryption on the fly.

Comment: @M.Deinum How do we do this?

Answer (score 4):

I solved similar problem by adding property source with highest precedence.

1. Add `META-INF/spring.factories` with content:

```
org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor=
  com.example.SettingsPropertiesAddingPostProcessor
```

2. SettingsPropertiesAddingPostProcessor implementation:

```
public class SettingsPropertiesAddingPostProcessor implements EnvironmentPostProcessor {
    private static final String SETTINGS_CONFIG_PATH = "/tmp/settings.properties";

    @Override
    public void postProcessEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment environment, SpringApplication application) {

        File settingsFile = new File(SETTINGS_CONFIG_PATH);
        if (!settingsFile.exists()) {
            log.debug("Config file not found, skipping adding custom property source");
            return;
        }

        log.debug("Config file found, adding custom property source");
        Properties props = loadProperties(settingsFile);
        MutablePropertySources propertySources = environment.getPropertySources();
        propertySources.addFirst(new PropertiesPropertySource("settings-source", props));

    }

    private Properties loadProperties(File f) {
        FileSystemResource resource = new FileSystemResource(f);
        try {
            return PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to load local settings from " + f.getAbsolutePath(), ex);
        }
    }
}
```

That should be all.

Comment: ok. so you are manually loading the properties in the `EnvironmentPostProcessor`. Did you figure out why the values were `null` in your case?

Comment: Your values are `null` because every solution you tried is invoked **before** the property sources are loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Following the advice of *@M. Deinum*, regarding using `"spring.config.additional-location"`, I have made a workaround as follows:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
public class MyApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("spring.config.additional-location", "file:/opt/app/conf/database.properties, file:/opt/app/conf/overrides.properties");
        SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplication(MyApp.class);
        springApplication.run(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        System.out.println("Setting properties onStartup");
        System.setProperty("spring.config.additional-location", "file:/opt/app/conf/database.properties, file:/opt/app/conf/overrides.properties");
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
    }
}
```

I have called the `System.setProperty()` in the `onStartup()` method of the `SpringBootServletInitializer` by overriding it as above and then invoked the super class' `onStartup()`

The latter part i.e. setting system property in `onStartup` method helps when the application is deployed in a web container like Tomcat.

Note: We can also *append* the properties to `spring.config.additional-location` instead of *set* so that other additional locations can also be added during runtime.